# libphonenumber library does not extract phone numbers with prefix +34 (0)

Tags: java, phone-number, libphonenumber

I am using libphonenumber to extract phone number from a given String but it has failed to extract numbers with "+34 (0)" prefix (+34 prefix works fine). It works fine with other extensions (ie :- +38 (0) ). It looks like it is linked to +34 combined with (0) pattern. Following is the code sample. Anyone experienced this before?

```java
String content = someString + "+34 (0)xxx - xxxxxx" + someString;
PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
Iterable<PhoneNumberMatch> intlNumbers = phoneNumberUtil.findNumbers(content, null);
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad sure, updated the question with a code sample

Answer (score 4):

You can use `parse` method then get `nationalNumber` and `countryCode`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberParseException {


    String content = "+34 (0)123 - 456789";
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    PhoneNumber phoneNumber =phoneNumberUtil.parse(content, null);
    System.out.println("Phone Number  = "+phoneNumber.getNationalNumber());
    System.out.println("Country Code = "+phoneNumber.getCountryCode());


}
```

**Result**

Phone Number  = 123456789

Country Code = 34

Comment: Yes. It works with the  `phoneNumberUtil.parse` method and the content should only contain the desired phone number. In my case the content is someString + "+34 (0)xxx - xxxxxx" + someString. And the content will have more than one number. That is why i was using `phoneNumberUtil.findNumber` method, which cannot parse that specific number.

Comment: What do you mean about someString, could you give me an example?

Comment: for example, "abc +49 (0)xxx - xxxxxx def +34 (0)xxx - xxxxxx ghi"

Comment: Aha! and you want to fetch `49xxx-xxxxx` and `34xxx-xxxx` from your string

Comment: Is this (`"test +49 (0)123 - 45678 test +34 (0)123 - 45634 test" `) an example of your scenario?

Comment: Yes that's correct :), Basically I want to fetch +49xxx-xxxxx and +34xxx-xxxxxx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206856/discussion-between-mehrdad-hosseinnejad-and-malith).

Answer (score 2):

[Telephone numbers in Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Spain) shows that 0 should have been 6 or 7. I think as not living in Spain.

Comment: More specifically, if I'm reading that page correctly, Spanish numbers have _no_ optional prefix. Within Spain, mobile numbers are `6xx xxx xxx` or `7xx xxx xxx`, and (normal) land-line numbers are `8xx xxx xxx` or `9xx xxx xxx`. Outside Spain, these are all `+34 6xx xxx xxx` etc.

Comment: @Malith In case of confusion, I was commenting on Joop's answer, not your comment (we both commented at almost the same time).

Comment: @TripeHound yes, amazing those assumptions about "(0)", driving on the right (not wrong) side of the road, 12.34.567 = 2-3 thousands separators. And the library seems remarkably high quality.